# Yii framework, using a module in another module

Tags: module, yii

How can I call a module in another module? This code works on my Controllers in Protected/Controllers:

```
$image = Yii::app()->image->save($photofile, 'some_name','uploadedGal');
```

But in the controller of my other module (`admin`)  I get this error.

```
Property "CWebApplication.image" is not defined.
```

I have defined the `image` module in my main config file:

```
'modules'=>array(
           'image'=>array(
                    'createOnDemand'=>true, // requires apache mod_rewrite enabled
                    'install'=>true, // allows you to run the installer
            ),
            'admin',

),
```

Comment: Maybe what you want is to define a custom CComponent.

Comment: No, I have my backend as a module `admin` and in the backend I need to use a module for image management `image`. I followed all  the instructions and it works in the frontend, but it doesnot work in the backend which is a module itself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to include the other module components in your module class. Something like this:

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setImport(array(
            'admin.models.*',
            'admin.components.*',
            'image.models.*',
            'image.components.*',
        ));
}
```

Comment: Also, I found that I could add this: `Yii::app()->setComponents(array('image'=>array('class'=>'application.modules.image.components.ImgManager')));` before using the other module...

Comment: @MahsaTeimourikia nice!! but it would be a little hard to maintain :P

Answer (score 2):

You can import the module components in the config/main.php like below:

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.modules.admin.components.*',
            ....
            ....
),
```

This way all models etc will be imported for you.